# Proving that a PRG is insecure

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I'm trying to show that the PRG $G$ defined as below is insecure for any binary matrix $A$.
\begin{align}
A&: m\times n& (n < m)\\
s&: n\times 1\\
G&: \{0, 1\}^n\rightarrow\{0, 1\}^{m} \\
&G(s)= (A\cdot s) \bmod{2}
\end{align}

As far as I know, I need to provide an adversary with non-negligible advantage, or prove that the PRG is predictable to show a PRG's insecurity. But I'm not sure where to start with. Is this the right approach?  How is the proof done?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the hint! But I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'found from the others.' Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: [reposted with clarification] Yes, you need to provide an adversary with a non-negligible advantage. Here, show how with knowledge of $A$, one bit of output (in fact, at least $m-n$ bits of output) can be computed (with certainty) from the other bits in the output.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I don't quite get the mathematical notation, can someone explain? My problem is, if I multiply A with s I get a vector of length n not m, which does not comply with the definition of G...

Comment: @Titanlord A matrix of size $m\times n $ when multiplied with another matrix of size $n\times t$ the result is $m \times t$

Comment: @kelalaka Ahh, so the output vector of $G$ has $m$ elements? And I assume $A$ represents a secret value?

Comment: @Titanlord $A$ defines the PRG, need to be known, and the $s$ is the seed.